# Why does spd-say stop speaking after a short while in the command line?

Tags: command-line, text-to-speech

I've noticed that whenever I'm in the command line and I try spd-say, it always stops shortly after it starts, and doesn't finish what I've told it to say.

For instance,

```
spd-say "moo moo farms are the best cow farms ever. They say moo, they don't pollute the earth, and they give milk. Visit moo moo farms today for only twelve easy payments of seventeen ninety five weekly!"
```

will only say `moo moo farms are the best cow farms. They say moo, they don't pollute the earth, and they gi`; and then it cuts off.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?
I'm using Linux Mint 19.0 on Aspire 5610Z and Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on Optiplex 755.

Comment: spd-say works in java, firefox (and probably Chrome's) speechSynthesis, and basically anywhere but the command line.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Linux Mint is off topic here. You can post this question at http://unix.stackexchange.com . Thank you.

Comment: It's not just linux mint I have this issue with; Linux Mint is the computer I use at home, and I use Linux Ubuntu at work, and the issue persists there.

Comment: If this is the case, please edit your question and add the Ubuntu version you use removing any reference to off topic distributions. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The reason is** `spd-say` times out and exits before completing the full text-to-speech output.

**To make `spd-say` wait until the full text has been read**, please add the option `--wait` after it. Like so:

```
spd-say --wait "moo moo farms are the best cow farms ever. They say moo, they don't pollute the earth, and they give milk. Visit moo moo farms today for only twelve easy payments of seventeen ninety five weekly!"
```

---

**Explanation - as requested by [Joshua Miller](https://askubuntu.com/users/929702/joshua-miller):**

`spd-say` sends text-to-speech output requests to `speech-dispatcher`. Please, read [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/spd-say.1.html).

However, if the text is too long, `spd-say` exits early... hence the need for the `--wait` option.

Other applications including your JAVA application might be sending text-to-speech output requests directly to `speech-dispatcher`. Please read the ( description ) part [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/speech-dispatcher.1.html).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But, just wondering, why did it work fine in my java application? I didn't have the `--wait` parameter.

Comment: @JoshuaMiller You are most welcome. `spd-say`  sends text-to-speech output request to `speech-dispatcher`. Please read https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/spd-say.1.html , but it exits early if the text is too long ... hence the need for the `--wait` option. Your JAVA application might be sending text directly to `speech-dispatcher. Please read the ( description ) part here`https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/speech-dispatcher.1.html .

Answer (score -1):

If the text is too long, you can put the content in a file 
spd-say "$(cat fileName)"

Comment: that basically means same thing.