# Manually install voices in festival

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

I am using **festival** as the natural reader in ubuntu, and I have been trying to download voices from CMU website and place them into `/usr/share/festival/voices/` However, none of the manually installation works.

Up till now no other voices are working except (voice_cmu_us_slt_arctic_hts) , anyone knows the correct instruction for manually installation?

```
sudo apt-get install festival
sudo apt-get install festvox-us-slt-hts
festival -i
festival> (voice_cmu_us_slt_arctic_hts) 
festival> (SayText "Don't hate me, I'm just doing my job!")
```

Comment: Related: [How to install and use latest Nitech HTS voices for festival on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1324381/968501)

Comment: Thanks, this post resolved my question.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks!